# Can't create WebJob in Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azureportal

I'm struggling to create a WebJob in the Azure portal, all I'm getting is a 'Failed to add web job' error, no other details.

I have already created a web job before with no issues but can't create a second one in the same App Service or in a different one. Have tried different names but no luck. I'm on the Basic App Service plan and as far as I know there is no limitation on a single web job.

Did anyone have this issue ?

Comment: Have you checked `Audit Logs`? Usually you would find some information there. Other place to look for is deployments under resource group. Since the deployment has failed, you should see something there. HTH.

Comment: Thanks. I have checked both Audit Logs and Deployments but no errors shown

Comment: A few things to clarify in your question: 1. Are you doing this in the new portal (portal.azure.com) or the old one (portal.azure.com)? 2. Continuous or Triggered WebJob? 3. Are you uploading a zip of directly a runnable file? 4. At which exact step are you seeing this error?

Comment: 1. New portal (portal.azure.com) 2. I have tried both Continuous and Triggered 3. I'm just trying to create the job from the portal then deploy it from Visual Studio 4. I go to App Services -> select my app service -> Settings -> Web Jobs -> Add -> enter the job details http://take.ms/NaA0O -> Press Ok -> error shown as notification. If I click on the error there aren't many details about it http://take.ms/FwnBr

. I have created a web job a few weeks ago in a similar way and it worked then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from David Ebbo and Gaurav Mantri I have figured out that I need to deploy the job from Visual Studio and it will be created automatically.

Seems like from the portal you can only create a web job if you upload the files too. If you don't upload any file it fails with a generic error.

Maybe there should be some kind of validation (make the File Upload field compulsory) or a more detailed error message.

Comment: But then how do you set the schedule with the cron expression? When I upload a file (which fails) it lets me enter a cron expression. However, when I publish with web deploy from Visual Studio, the web job is created but I am left with no way to enter the cron expression. This is pretty janky.

Answer (score 6):

I recently encountered this error too, and to solve it I basically had to deploy the web job manually from a zip file. I Originally found out how to do this from an old azure promo video that I now can't find, so just for the next poor soul that has to do this I have included them here.

1. Build the project. Note that if you have converted to .Net Standard and the VS 2017 style you will need to build the project as a console app rather than a class library.
2. Go to the bin folder and zip up the contents of the release folder. Note that the exe needs to be at the root of this zip or it won't work.
3. In the Azure portal go to the App Service -> Web Jobs and click on Add.
4. Give the Web job a name and select the zip file you just created.
5. For continuous web jobs just click create.
6. For Scheduled web jobs you will need to provide a CRON expression. Something like 0 0 5 * * * for every day at 05:00.

The web job should now be deployed.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same issue while trying to add a Web Job. Turns out changing from IE to Chrome solved the problem. Worth a try if others experience the same problems.

Comment: mid 2019 and the chrome only bug still exists.